# Cannot get principal id on my Spock test

Tags: grails, spock

I have a controller like this :

```
@Secured(['ROLE_USER','IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY'])
    def userprofile(){
        def user = User.get(springSecurityService.principal.id)
        params.id = user.id
        redirect (action : "show", params:params)
    }
```

I want to test the controller above controller in spock, so I wrote a test code like this:

```
def 'userProfile test'() {

        setup:
        mockDomain(User,[new User(username:"amtoasd",password:"blahblah")])

        when:
        controller.userprofile()

        then:
        response.redirectUrl == "/user/show/1"
    }
```

When I run my test, this test fails with this error message :

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot get property 'principal' on null object
    at mnm.schedule.UserController.userprofile(UserController.groovy:33)
```

And in case of Integration test:

```
class UserSpec extends IntegrationSpec {

    def springSecurityService

    def 'userProfile test'() {

        setup:
        def userInstance = new User(username:"antoaravinth",password:"secrets").save()
        def userInstance2 = new User(username:"antoaravinthas",password:"secrets").save()
        def usercontroller = new UserController()
        usercontroller.springSecurityService = springSecurityService

        when:
        usercontroller.userprofile()

        then:
        response.redirectUrl == "/user/sho"
    } 

}
```

I get the same error as well.

What went wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't appear to have done anything to provide a real or mock `springSecurityService`, so of course it's null (there's no dependency injection in unit tests; you have to mock everything that's not provided by the unit test class). Adding this in `setup:` should work:

```
controller.springSecurityService = [principal: [id: 42]]
```

Comment: nope doing so throw's an another error: `groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: id for class: java.lang.Integer
 at mnm.schedule.UserController.userprofile(UserController.groovy:33)`

Comment: I updated the answer since I missed a level. You may also need to change `42` to `42L`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But In this case, even though the error has been disappeared, the line `def user = User.get(springSecurityService.principal.id)` in `userProfile` method now executes to `null`. It is not returning the user object!

Comment: I did a mistake, I was passing `42` in my code as the `id` value, when I changed that one to `1` it does work as intended.

Answer (score 0):

As for me, I've created nested class. I did have problems with

```
springSecurityService.getPrincipal()
```

cause it's read only thing

```
class SService {

    User principal

    void setPrincipal(User user){
        this.principal = user
    }

    User getPrincipal(){
        return this.principal
    }
}
```

An then in your test

```
def setup() {
    User first = User.findByUsername('admin') ?: new User(
            username: 'admin',
            password: 'password',
            email: "first@email.com",
            lastName: 'First',
            firstName: 'First').save(flush: true, failOnError: true)
    SService sservice = new SService()
    controller.springSecurityService = new SService()
    controller.springSecurityService.setPrincipal(first)
}
```